# Riemann integrals real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

How would I do this question?

$$
\int_{-1}^{2}(4x - x^2)dx
$$

I am using a similar method that I did for a different question but I think my problem is I don't know how to tackle the $x^2$.
I am getting an answer of $15$, but $15$ is not the answer.

Comment: Hint: You know how to differentiate $x^3$.

Comment: I am assuming because the function is monotone decreasing on this interval that I can pick a partition that I want, so I pick delta xi = 3/n. And then I find that xi= (3/n)*n*(n+1) = 3/2(n+1), so I sub that into my xi.......
Which is lim n->infinity 3/n * (4 * (sum from i=1 to n xi) - (sum from i=1 to n of (xi)^2)). I don't know how to get my value for xi^2?

Comment: It is unclear what methods you can apply. a) work with the definition, i.e. Riemann sums of sufficiently fine partitions or b) use some known integration formulas for wellknown functions or c) use a knwon result about the connection between integrals and derivatives. - From your comment it seems you should work with a)? You may wish to edit this information to your question. (Also, if you wrongly obtain 15, add the way you arrived at that result)

Comment: ok just gonna post an exmaple of another problem I did.
We are looking for the using riemann sum and we are choosing a partition deltaxi. deltaxi=b-a/n
so. for, integral from 0 to 2 (4-2x)dx. We know integral from 0 to 2 f(x) = lim n-> infinity sum i from 1 to n of f(x) * delta xi. So, for this particular example we have delta xi = 2/n. And lim n-> infinity 2/n*(sum i=1->n 4 - sum i=1 -> n 2*xi)
We find value of xi by, 2*sum i=1 to  n xi = 2*(2/n)*(n*(n+1)/2) simplify to = 2(n+1), for our constant 4 we just multiply by n when using riemann sum so plug in and we get,

Comment: lim n-> infinity 2/n*(4n-2*(n+1))
= lim n-> infinity ( 8 - (4/n)*n + 4/n) = 4

This is the method I am trying to apply to the question I posted above but I'm not getting the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Riemann definition, we first have to define the partition and the interpolation points. In the region $[-1,0]$ we use $x_i=-\frac{i}{N}$, and every interval has length $\frac{1}{N}$. In the region $[0,2]$ we use $x_i=2\frac{i}{N}$ and every interval has length $\frac{2}{N}$. It follows that the integral is approximated by Riemann sums:
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^2x^2dx&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{N}\left(-\frac{i}{N}\right)^2\right]+\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{2}{N}\left(2\frac{i}{N}\right)^2\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{N^3}\sum_{i=1}^Ni^2\right]+8\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{N^3}\sum_{i=1}^Ni^2\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{N^3}\frac{1}{6}N(N+1)(2N+1)\right]+8\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{N^3}\frac{1}{6}N(N+1)(2N+1)\right]\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6N^3}+\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{4N(N+1)(2N+1)}{3N^3}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{8}{3}=3
\end{align}

Here we used that $1^2+2^2+\cdots+N^2=\frac{1}{6}N(N+1)(2N+1)$ and that the limit of the ratio of two polynomials is determined by the ratio of the leading coefficients.

Do you understand which intervals are convenient to choose and how to do the summation?

Comment: Hello,
Why do we use xi = -i/N in first region?
Thanks

Comment: When doing a summation, it is not relevant whether you sum from left to right of from right to left. It is allowed to sum from right to left, and go from $-\frac{1}{N}$ to $-\frac{N}{N}=-1$.

Comment: I thought it would be i/N because the integral goes from -1 to 0, 0-(-1)/N = 1/N, this is why I thought it would be i/N, I am still not understanding why it is -i/N could you make it a bit more clear if you can. Thanks

Comment: Every point (except $0$) in $[-1,0]$ has a negative $x$-coordinate, so $x_i$ must be negative. Do you understand this?

Comment: Yes, 
Do we always break up the interval at 0 or do we only break it up because the parabola is no longer monotone inc?

Comment: Only because it's easier to calculate. I rather calculate with $x_i=\frac{1}{n}$ than $x_i=1+\frac{1}{n}$ or such an expression.

Comment: @Thijs I made an account but I am the same person who asked the question above.
Trying to apply what you did above to the integral (4x-x^2) from -1 to 2.
I get -4.5 as my answer but it should be -5.
Here is what I did, I said, xi=3i/N, and every interval has length 3/N.
so integral became = lim N-> infty sum i=1 to N [3/N*((3i/N) - (3i/n)^2)]
= lim N -> infty sum i=1 to N [(9i/N^2) - (27i^2/N^3)]
= lim N -> infty sum i=1 to N [(9/N^2)*((N)(N+1)/2) - (27/N^3)*((N)(N+1)(2N+1)/6)]
When I reduce this I get, 9/2 - 54/6 = -9/2 The answer is supposed to be 3.

Comment: In your calculation, you integrate from $0$ to $3$, instead of from $-1$ to $2$.